# {Object|Array|Anything} to string with respect to recursion limit in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there a straightforward way in PHP to get an arbitrary complex value into a string without triggering recursion limits? For example, passing an hugely nested object and specifying I want only 2 levels deep.

What I want to avoid is getting an error on var_export or var_dump, even if that means that I get less accurate output.

Thanks!

Clarification: I want to use the string for logging usage, so debuggers are not applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe having a super class looking like this:

```
class Dumpable {

    function varDump($max_depth = 2) {
        return self::dump((array)$this, $max_depth);
    }

    public static function dump($arr, $max_depth = 2) {
        if( $max_depth > 0 ) {
            $new_arr = array();
            foreach( $arr as $key => $val ) {
                if( $val instanceof Dumpable) {
                    $new_arr[$key] = $val->varDump($max_depth-1);
                }
                elseif( is_object($val) ) {
                    $new_arr[$key] = self::dump((array)$val, $max_depth-1);
                }
                elseif( is_array($val) ) {
                    $new_arr[$key] = self::dump($val, $max_depth-1);
                }
                else {
                    $new_arr[$key] = $val;
                }
            }
            return $new_arr;
        }
        elseif(is_object($arr)) {
           return 'Object:'.get_class($arr).'...';
        }
        else {
            return 'array...';
        }
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return print_r($this->varDump(), true);
    }
}
```

Then you're able to call `var_dump( $my_dumpable_obj->varDump() );` when wanting to dump an an object extending Dumpable. If your server supports php 5.4 it might be better to use this functions in a Trait instead.

Comment: Thanks, but that 's only for arrays, no?

Comment: You can cast an object to an array as well, but you will only get the public variables... I will make some additions to the code in a second..

Comment: Sweet and practical! Thank you!

Comment: On a second hand it feels as if you should rename the dump-function to "toArray" instead, since that what the function actually does

Answer (score 0):

I do not know any straighforward way for this - only the opposite: Using XDEBUG (http://xdebug.org/)  and playing with the `xdebug.var_display_max_depth` setting.

As far as I known XDEBUG does a better var_dump than PHP...

Comment: My bad for not clarifying, sorry. I want this so I can pass it to a logging class, so xdebug is not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

If you don'T need runnable code, you could use `print_r()` which can handle more than `var_export()`